# Timezone issue in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

I have the following problem: From an API I get two strings representing a date and a time in the Europe/Berlin timezone. My server and database run in UTC time. So I want to convert the date and time to a UTC datetime object before storing it in my database. How can I do this? Is it possible to create a Date object out of a string in a different timezone than is set in the system?

Example:

Input (Europe/Berlin timezone):
date: string = "2023-06-15"
time: string = "15:30"

I want to convert a date object to UTC time like 2023-06-15T13:30:00.000Z.

I tried things like this:

```
const datetime = new Date(
    new Date(
        date + ' ' + time)
    ).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin'})
);
```

But this works in the wrong direction.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use moment-timezone library as below

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const date = "2023-06-15";
const time = "15:30";
const timezone = "Europe/Berlin";

const berlinDateTime = moment.tz(`${date} ${time}`, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", timezone);
const utcDateTime = berlinDateTime.utc();

const formattedUtcDateTime = utcDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS") + "Z";

console.log(formattedUtcDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Day.JS library: https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone

By the way, I would use a library other than Moment, since Moment itself states that the library is no longer state of the art (refer https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status)

Hope this helps!